# Set up Notepad++ and NppExec to print unicode characters from python

Tags: python, unicode, notepad++, nppexec

I have an utf-8 encoded file `cjk.py`:

```
print("打印")
```

Unsurprisingly, running `python cjk.py` yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cjk.py", line 1, in <module>
    print('\u6253\u5370')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

Yet running `idle -r cjk.py` works perfectly:

```
打印
```

**Can I configure notepad++'s NppExec plugin to behave like Idle?** I've trying setting input and output encoding to UTF-8, to no avail (same exception as when running `python cjk.py` from the console)

Comment: Hi, I am encountering the same problem myself. Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Clément I don't see the same problem, rather it prints the content `打印`. I have used this line `#coding=utf-8` at the top of the program. What python version are you using?

Comment: You don't specify which version of Python and which localisation and which version of which OS you are using. I will guess that it is Python 3.3 and some version of Windows, perhaps Windows 7, localised for French as used in France. Am I someone correct?

Comment: Indeed; French or France, Windows 8, and Python 3.3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fixed it.

Add `env_set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`
just below `C:\Python27\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` 
in the dialog box when you press **F6**.

Worked like a charm for me, hope it helps.

Source: http://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/672146/thread/d94ff609/

Comment: Note that you also need to update the NppExec Console Output... option to be UTF-8, otherwise characters don't print correctly.

Comment: thank you @yoyo! On Notepad++ 8.4.8 one must go to Plugin menu > NppExec >"Console Output..." > tick UTF-8. Et voila, problème résolu.